# Change a cell address to row,column in Excel sheet using C#

Tags: c#, excel

> I would like to convert an excel cell 
>   eg : A1 to 1,1 G6 to 7,6 etc
>
> Does any one have idea for it?
>   Note : This is required for a C# application.

Comment: I have thought of parsing 
eg for K56 first seperate K and 56 ,
Then convert k to a number using logic A being 1 and so on finally getting 11,56

Comment: Got a solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951517/convert-a-to-1-b-to-2-z-to-26-and-then-aa-to-27-ab-to-28 to convert column to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just treat the alphabetic portion as a number in base 26, with A = 0 (in Excel, the column names eventually repeat, as in "AA").

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly try

```
=COLUMN(G6) & "," & ROW(G6)
```

This will return

> **7,6**

Comment: I never knew & was a concatenation operator. All these years using the CONCATENATE function. Oh the wasted keystrokes!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this as an Excel formula then this will work

```
=CONCATENATE(ROW(G6),",",COLUMN(G6))
```

However if you have the cell reference in a string then you will need to use the INDIRECT function as follows

```
=CONCATENATE(ROW(INDIRECT("G6")),",",COLUMN(INDIRECT("G6")))
```

This gives a result of 6,7 (Row,Column) as specified in the title.

Comment: Hi,Steve I got true and false result using this formula

Comment: Hi,Again using indirect worked but how ever I am trying to do this in a C# application so I am still looking a solution Thank you.