# convert a given char varialble to string, representing it's code in my encoding

Tags: c#, string, encoding, char, encode

I want to write a txt file. Some of the chars need to be escaped in a way: \'c1, where c1 is the code of a char in encoding 1251.

How can I convert a given char varialble to string, representing it's code in my encoding?

I found a way to do this for utf, but no way for other ecnodings. For utf variant there is Char.ConvertToUtf32() method.

Comment: Actually I don't have a code, because I don't know how to achive this. Task grows from the way rtf encodes latin characters. It just escapes it in a way \'c1.

Comment: So, you're trying to put RTF in a text file?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951517/convert-a-to-1-b-to-2-z-to-26-and-then-aa-to-27-ab-to-28-column-indexes-to I think this is what you are trying to do or MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// get the encoding
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);

// for each character you want to encode
byte b = encoding.GetBytes("" + c)[0];
string hex = b.ToString("x");
string output = @"\'" + hex;
```

Comment: When you use non-captial `"x"` in format string, `.ToLower()` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I convert a given char varialble to string, representing it's code in my encoding?

Try something like this:

```
    var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");

    char myCharacter = 'д'; // Cyrillic 'd'

    byte code = enc.GetBytes(new[] { myCharacter, })[0];

    Console.WriteLine(code.ToString());      // "228" (decimal)
    Console.WriteLine(code.ToString("X2"));  // "E4" (hex)
```

Comment: Note that in newer versions of .NET you must call `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);` before you can use legacy encodings like `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251")`.