# String to Integer Mapping

Tags: java, algorithm

Does any one have algorithm or logic to Convert A to 1 ,B to 2, ... ,Z to 26 and then ,AA to 27, AB to 28 and so on BUT BA or cb or cbe or any  string which has  letters  in descending order should not be numbered a for eg: BB should be 53 as BA is not numbered .this question is very similar to [Convert A to 1 B to 2 ... Z to 26 and then AA to 27 AB to 28 (column indexes to column references in Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951517/convert-a-to-1-b-to-2-z-to-26-and-then-aa-to-27-ab-to-28-column-indexes-to) but with a slight difference as mentioned above

Comment: "A" is a string with letters in descending order.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: im ok with just d algorithm or a hint towards it,but java is what i would use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to have limited amount of mappings

1. Generate all mapping you want in order you need

   `A, B, C, ... , Z, AA, AB, ... ,AZ, BA, BB, ..., BZ`
2. Filter mappings with letters in non-descending order

   `A, B, C, ... , AA, AB, ... ,AZ, BB, ..., BZ` (BA disappeared!)

   To check if the string is in non-descending order, just compare it to its sorted version.
3. Enumerate!

Comment: Thx so much,for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Assume your first character in cell A1 and second character in cell B1, the following formula should help you to calculate the value

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),0,CODE(A1)-CODE("A")+1)*26+(CODE(B1)-CODE("A")+1)
```

For only A to Z, A1 is blank and put the single character in B1.

Comment: i actually want to  do it programatically and nt excel anyways ill see if your formula helps